# Google AppEngine Query Sort

Tags: sorting, google-app-engine

How can I sort the results of Query using more than 1 property?

For example, I want to sort my Query results by 'lastname' and sort by 'firstname' in each group of 'lastname'.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

Person.all().order("lastname").order("firstname")

Comment: Yes, I did. However, order("firstname") breaks the grouping on "lastname".

Comment: Surely that's a bug, then. http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_order says "Adds an ordering for the results. Results are ordered starting with the first order added".

Comment: Works For Me. This is pretty basic functionality - you can definitely chain order clauses like this.

Answer (score 1):

Just use two orders separated by comma, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM person ORDER BY lastname, firstname
```

See [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queriesandindexes.html) for more details.

Comment: I can use GqlQuery instead, but I wonder if Query supports this kind of ordering in any way. I could not find any example on the API documentation.

Comment: Oh, I didn't get that from the question... Did you try `.order("lastname, firstname")`?

Comment: That does not seem like a valid argument for order.  I'll use GqlQuery and move on. Thanks for the help!